# Cypress - Angular code - button sometimes are recognized and sometimes are not

Tags: cypress-component-test-runner

I am trying to build automation tests , I am using Cypress on an application that is written with Angular .
There are buttons at the page , the problem is that sometimes the Cypress activates those buttons and in other runs the same cypress code not succeeded to activate those same buttons.
Please help me to understand how to write Cypress code that always will recognizes those buttons (Angular code)?
Thanks,
Ilanit

I recognize those button with cypress application using the arrow